# Compute Usage in KQL

Tags: azure, kql, kusto-explorer, azure-resource-graph

[Usage - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/usage/list?tabs=HTTP)

I'm trying to get Compute Usage List using KQL in Azure, you can find it in above link for reference.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "unit": "Count",
      "currentValue": 17,
      "limit": 19,
      "name": {
        "value": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "localizedValue": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
      }
    }
  ],
  "nextLink": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

What I'm expecting is where that type of data is located in which table.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to query azure resource graph with KQL? The onboarding for compute usage to ARG is still going on. Currently only part of subscriptions are onboarded. But if you have access to the onboarded subscriptions, you will be able to see results in ARG with this query:
quotaresources | where type contains "microsoft.compute/locations/usages" | limit 100

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i cant find  that quotaresources in Azure Resource Graph Explorer

Answer (score 0):

*As you added the reference MSDoc, one method for obtaining location usage details is through an API call to the specified Url.*

Otherwise,

> Compute Usage in KQL:

Search for `Azure Resource Graph Explorer` in the Azure Portal. All resource usage information can be checked and computed individually as well as with locations.

[image]

Go to the `resources` table under `table` section to see all the provider categories, as shown:

Eg: Disks resource usage:-

```bash
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/disks"
```

Locationwise:

```bash
resources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/locations"
```

***Or***

*To check community gallery resources, execute the below query table.*

```bash
communitygalleryresources
| where type == "microsoft.compute/locations/communitygalleries"
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually I cant find, In which particular table that Compute usage data available :)

Comment: Check resources & communitygalleryresources tables.